# django.contrib.auth.views.login returns Anonymous user

Tags: django, django-authentication

I want to login my user after registration, but when call `login(request, user)` then `request.user` is still AnonymousUser.

```
def register(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            pwd = form.cleaned_data['password1']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=pwd)
            if user is not None and user.is_active:
                auth_views.login(request, user)
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()

    return render(request, 'registration.html', {'form' : form})
```

When calling `login` in my own login method, it works correct. But in

```
`register` view not:
def login(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None and user.is_active:
                auth_views.login(request, user)
                return redirect(reverse('chat'))
            else:
                return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()

    return render(request, 'login.html', {'form':form})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def my_view(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            # Redirect to a success page.
        else:
            # Return a 'disabled account' error message
            ...
    else:
        # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
        ...
```

And check your session settings

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to define the Auth user in your settings file? If not, you should add the following line to your settings.py:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'your_app.your_usermodel'
```